# How to draw a Feynman Diagram with current j (feynMP)

Tags: feynmp, feynmp-auto

I know how to create this diagram, but I dont know how to add the currents (j1 and j2).

Here is my code, I got it from https://wiki.physik.uzh.ch/cms/latex:feynman

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.4cm]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\marrow}[5]{%
    \fmfcmd{style_def marrow#1
        expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 #2 withpen pencircle scaled 0.4;
        label.#3(btex #4 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted 6 #2);
        enddef;}
    \fmf{marrow#1,tension=0}{#5}}

\begin{fmffile}{dgs}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(110,60)
        \fmfleft{i1,i2}
        \fmfright{o1,o2}
        \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i2}
        \fmflabel{$e^-$}{o2}
        \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{i1}
        \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
        \marrow{ea}{ up }{top}{$p_1$}{i2,v2}
        \marrow{eb}{down}{bot}{$p_3$}{v2,o2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
        \marrow{ma}{down}{bot}{$p_2$}{i1,v1}
        \marrow{mb}{ up }{top}{$p_4$}{v1,o1}
        \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma$}{v2,v1}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far. Do you want the arrows for the currents styled like in the above example?

Comment: I've edited and posted my code. The arrows style is not important, I just want to put the currents.

Comment: You have an unmatched `\]`, but even without it I cannot reproduce the diagram. Please verify that your code compiles and produces the output you think it does.

Comment: I Corrected it. Thanks.